# How to show a quiz in HTML over Vimeo video in fullscreen mode

Tags: html, jquery, css, video, vimeo

for sure it is easy when the video is not fullscreen.

here the structure

```
.boiteVideo iframe{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#affiche{
z-index: 2147483647;
position: absolute;
left:200px;
top: 200px;
}

<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 boiteVideo">
<iframe id="player1" src="xxxxx" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
<div id="affiche" class="text-success well"><h1>Un test overlay</h1></div>
</div>
```

I use Vimeo video and pyayer.js to show the quiz at good moment during the video

Everything work well the #affiche is over the video but in fullscreen nothing to do.

When I look the structure of Vimeo in fullscreen I see a class player, vp-video-wrapper, vp-video, vp-player-ui-overlays.

Someone have an idea it will be very appreciate

thanks

i try every class like player,vp-video-wrapper,vp-video,vp-player-ui-overlays
i can see in fullscreen to show the <div id="affiche" and nothing work.

also i try to include this div in the iframe like this

```
$("#affiche").appendTo($("iframe"));
```

Comment: You can not manipulate iframes through Jquery. You could upload the video on your server and put it in a video HTML tag.

Comment: Do you mean i can not .find() a class or something like that

Comment: @poete You need to do a `requestFullscreen` on the parent Div itself, then it will fullscreen along with its children (_ie:_ the Vimeo and the Affiche as child elements). It might help to give the Div an ID for easy access later by code. So.. **(1)** Create a button to "View Quiz in Fullscreen" as its label. **(2)** When button is clicked it will run a function that makes your Div [requestFullscreen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/requestFullscreen).

Comment: @VC.One thanks so much it working. Here i did for every one who wants to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#btnFullScreen").click(function() {
  var element = document.querySelector(".boiteVideo");
    
  element.requestFullscreen();
});
```

```css
.boiteVideo iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#affiche {
  z-index: 2147483647;
  position: absolute;
  left:200px;
  top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<button id="btnFullScreen">Open Video in Fullscreen Mode</button>

<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 boiteVideo">
  <iframe id="player1" src="xxxxx"></iframe>
  <div id="affiche" class="text-success well">
    <h1>Un test overlay</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```